# Minimum Spannig Tree clustering using max standard deviation reduction

Tags: graph, cluster-analysis

Me and my team in college are working on a project which take an image and quantizate it using **MST**
it's a college project , so we are asked to cluster the **MST** into **K** clusters , and we are asked to find the value of **K** through steps as follow:

1. Computes the standard deviation of the edges in minimum spanning tree and store it.
2. Choose an edge that leads to **max standard deviation reduction** once it is removed to obtain a set of 
     two disjoint sub-trees.
3. Compute standard deviation reduction in current iteration.item.
4. Repeat steps (2) and (3) until convergence -> the difference between standard deviation reduction in current iteration and previous iteration is very small < 0.0001.

I searched over the internet about the meaning of **max standard deviation reduction** but i found nothing.
I know waht is the standrad deviation but i don't know if it's defferent from the standrad deviation reduction.
I thought about findign the edge that lead to **Max standrd deviation** using **Z-Score** but i don't know if this is will give me the **Max standrd deviation reduction** or not.

Comment: Since it is a college project, why don't you ask your instructor for clarification of the assignment.

Comment: Of course I did , but it seems that they got the description for this project from the internet and they are not sure about what we are really should do

Comment: Well, and probably it got translated at least twice during that process? Well, it's their assignment - they need to be able to clarify this.